# Django collectstatic not working on production with S3, but same settings work locally

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, collectstatic

I've been moving around some settings to make more defined local and production environments, and I must have messed something up.

Below are the majority of relevant settings. If I move the production.py settings (which just contains AWS-related settings at the moment) to base.py, I can update S3 from my local machine just fine. Similarly, if I keep those AWS settings in base.py and push to production, S3 updates appropriately. In addition, if I print something from production.py, it does print. However, if I make production.py my "local" settings on manage.py, or when I push to Heroku with the settings as seen below, S3 is not updating.

What about my settings is incorrect? (Well, I'm sure a few things, but specifically causing S3 not to update?)

Here's some relevant code:

`__init__.py` (in the directory with base, local, and production)

```
from cobev.settings.base import *
```

`base.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
    'storages',
]

...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "global_static"),
                    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media", )
                    ]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

`local.py`

```
# local_settings.py
from .base import *

...

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

`production.py`

```
from .base import *

# AWS Settings

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'cobev'

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'cobev.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

# End AWS
```

`wsgi.py`

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "cobev.settings.production")

application = get_wsgi_application()

from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

`manage.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "cobev.settings.local") 
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Where are `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` coming from? Have you checked that these are correctly defined in the Heroku environment? Do the keys contain any special characters (`$`, `@`) that haven't been escaped (this will cause problems on Heroku)?

Comment: They are stored as environment variables on heroku. I’ll triple check, but those vars work if the AWS code is in base.py instead of production.py.

Comment: What updates the S3? Is it a django management command or you are updating S3 from Django admin or etc on files uploads or etc?

Comment: @AlexandrShurigin I think `storages` takes care of that with the `collectstatic` command on push to heroku (or manually)

Comment: Well, First maybe I'm wrong but, why try to use WhiteNoise when you what to use S3 ???? That makes no sense for me.  Check the doc : http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/legacy-2.x/index.html 1st line

Comment: @Sigdev likely legacy from setting up heroku a while back. I'll look into that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let me try, as discovered in comments from the question, you do S3 update using `collectstatic`, but this is a management command which is called using `manage.py` file where you set `cobev.settings.local` as settings which are not equal to `cobev.settings.production` which is used for `wsgi.py` file.

I think you should manage your settings file using, normal Django way, OS environment variable named `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`.

For sure you should be able to set it in any production environment you are running.

Answer (score 2):

Then if that can help here is my config for AWS/Django/S3 in production :

Common Static config :

```
# STATIC FILE CONFIGURATION
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-root
STATIC_ROOT = str(ROOT_DIR('staticfiles'))

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    str(APPS_DIR.path('static'))
]

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-finders
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder'
]
```

Common Media config :

```
# MEDIA CONFIGURATION
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root
MEDIA_ROOT = str(APPS_DIR('media'))

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-url
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Production Static config :

```
# STATIC CONFIG PRODUCTION
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# See: http://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket-name-production'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'YOUR_KEY_ID'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY'
AWS_S3_HOST = "s3.amazonaws.com"
AWS_S3_URL = 'https://{bucker_name}.s3.amazonaws.com/'.format(bucker_name=AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)

AWS_LOCATION = 'static/'

AWS_S3_URL_PROTOCOL = 'https:'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'static.mydomain.com' # I use sub domaine to serve static 

STATIC_URL = '{AWS_S3_URL_PROTOCOL}//{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}'.format(
    AWS_S3_URL_PROTOCOL=AWS_S3_URL_PROTOCOL,
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN=AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN,
    AWS_LOCATION=AWS_LOCATION)

AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False

AWS_IS_GZIPPED = True
AWS_EXPIREY = 60 * 60 * 24 * 14

# For s3boto
AWS_HEADERS = {
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=%d, s-maxage=%d, must-revalidate' % (AWS_EXPIREY, AWS_EXPIREY)
}

# For s3boto3
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=%d' % AWS_EXPIREY,
}

AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True
#AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = True

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'config.storages.StaticStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'config.storages.DefaultStorage'



# MEDIA S3 CONFIG PRODUCTION
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

AWS_MEDIA_DIR = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = AWS_S3_URL + AWS_MEDIA_DIR + '/'
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL
```

Here is my StaticStorage Class :

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage


class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'static'
    file_overwrite = False


class DefaultStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = ''
    file_overwrite = False
```

After That I add command in the folder .ebextensions in .config file for collectstatic :

```
# ./ebextensions/02_container_commands.config file : 

container_commands:
  0.3.0.push.static.to.s3:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --ignore=.scss --noinput"
    leader_only: true
    ignoreErrors: true
```

Comment: I hope that will help u ;)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using [Whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/index.html). Whitenoise allows django to serve its static files. It is different approach if you want to serve them from AWS.

So, you need to **remove Whitenoise** in order to utilize django-storages. Remove it from settings, middleware, wsgi.py, etc.

Also, you can remove everything from `__init__.py` in settings - settings file to be used is set by `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` env variable.

---

According to your `STATICFILES_DIRS`, `media` directory is included as static files. It is preferred for media to be served separately from static files (one of differences - static files are more likely to be cached and gziped) - i.e. also with AWS but from separate S3 bucket.

You may also add [AWS CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) as CDN in front of your buckets later.